# Blocking code in Task of FreeRTOS

Tags: adc, stm32, c, gsm, freertos

Today is my first day on FreeRTOS. I want to use it in STM32F103 for simple task handling as reading data from analog sensor and sending remotely using GSM module.

I want to know what are the do's and don'ts of writing a good task in FreeRTOS? Specifically is it allowed to write a blocking code, for() loop while() loop, inside a task?

Comment: You should read [a book](https://freertos.org/Documentation/161204_Mastering_the_FreeRTOS_Real_Time_Kernel-A_Hands-On_Tutorial_Guide.pdf) on RTOS usage.

Comment: See [this FreeRTOS article on tasks](https://www.freertos.org/implementing-a-FreeRTOS-task.html). You basicly should **always** write your tasks as infinite loops.

Comment: Judging by this and your other question, i'm not sure you know what a task is, or what an OS is useful for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends a little bit on what you're implementing but as mentioned in the comments as tasks usually handle/emit reocurring events they all should contain an infinit loop so this is not a **don't**.

What you should keep in mind when introducing multiple tasks is the required processing time and the fact that a context switch requires resources and processing time as well. To reduce unecessary context switching you shouldn't use normal wait loops in your tasks as you might would do in a normal single threaded application, use the delay functions provided by the FreeRTOS instead to set the task asleep.

Further, as you cannot control when a context switch happens, don't forget to protect any shared resources with mutexes.